# How to transfer specific number to date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

Need to transfer numeric columns with numbers like '201 711' and '201 806' to dates like '2017-11-01' and '2018-06-01' ('YYYY-MM-01'). When I try this

```
select to_date(debt_max_period,'YYYY-MM') as date1 from debt;
```

I get

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function to_date(numeric, unknown) does not
> exist.

Will be thankful for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the number to a text/varchar value. As the number doesn't contain the `-`  character, you also need to remove that from your format mask.

```
to_date(debt_max_period::text, 'yyyymm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle -

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(START_DATE,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') STARTDATE from account
```

You can use like below as well.
Postgresql -

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(START_DATE::text,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') STARTDATE from account
```